# Adding image background on IONIC 2 Component

Tags: ionic2

I wanted to add image as background in one of my components.
I'm not really sure how to actually locate my image file.
I put it inside src/assets/images folder.

This is my scss for the component:

```
page-login {
  body {
      background-image: url(assets/images/cool.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

Nothing seems happening.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
page-login{
   ion-content {
      background-image: url('../assets/images/cool.jpg')!important;
      background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

I assumed your page is in `src/pages/page1/page-login.scss`.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks!